# How can I activate buttons or open and close things without reloading?

Tags: battlefield-4

Each time I activate something such as a button or open or close a crate, my character will reload if the current gun doesn't have a full clip. This is because on Playstation consoles the square button for activating the item is the same as the reload button.

Is this a bug or am I pressing it for an incorrect interval?

Comment: I am pretty sure that when they ask you to press buttons, you have to PRESS and HOLD the Xbutton

Comment: It is like that on every system, besides pc since they have more button options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On consoles, press and hold the button and it will not reload your weapon. Tapping the button reloads.

On a PC I believe there is a separate key for actions, so if you have this problem, change your key bindings.

Comment: On pc reload is with `R` and action is with `E`